# Entity Framework 4.0 - EntityDataSource Many-To-Many Relation Query?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to perform a selection by 2 Entity ( AppRoles and AppUsers) ,

If in SQL, i would do this, For example :

```
SELECT u.*, r.* FROM AppUsers u ,AppRoles r WHERE u.RoleID = r.RoleID
```

Also it can be done using LINQ Syntax in Code-Behind.

However, i don't know how to do in EntityDataSource

Below is my mark-up :

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsUsers" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=ReferralDBEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="ReferralDBEntities" EnableFlattening="True" 
    EntitySetName="AppUsers"
    Include="AppRoles"
    Select="it.AppUsers, it.AppRoles"
    Where="it.AppUsers.RoleID = it.AppRoles.RoleID"
    >
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

But it show the error.

Comment: "But it show the error." - **what error??**

Comment: Something like : System.Data.EntitySqlException: 'Address' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[CCWinCustomer.CustomerAddress(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract properties out of collections, you must use a sub-query to iterate over the collection., near multipart identifier, line 9, column 26..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An older post not answered.

Try removing the Select="it.AppUsers, it.AppRoles"

Otherwise I am not sure how the relationship between your two tables is setup in the EDMX. You may want to check those also.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want a list of all users in each role

and assuming you have a 3 table structure i.e. users, UserInRoles, UserRole

Then

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsUsers" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="name=ReferralDBEntities" 
   DefaultContainerName="ReferralDBEntities" EnableFlattening="True" 
   EntitySetName="UserInRoles"
   Include="UserRole, User"
   Select="it.User.FullName, it.UserRole.Name">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Job done